# Javascript function document.querySelectorAll works weird on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, user-interface, browser

I am trying to get elements by the Chrome developer console using the function *document.querySelectorAll*, the point is that it does not return any element, however I see the elements on the Elements tabs.

I was wondering whether someone has faced similar issues. Shall I change some options on the browser configuration?

By the way, the Chrome version is 63 on MAC. In addition, the page I am working on has an iframe html tag, may this be the reason of the strange behavior?

This is what I get from the Developer Console

[image]

And this is what I get from the elements tabs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: which page are you calling in your browser?

Comment: The page is under development on the company I work for that unfortunately is not public.

Comment: Looks correct to me, on Chrome Canary 64:
https://screencast.com/t/nyDgHA0QE

Comment: @pafede2 You shouldn't provide links to the code anyways. You should add code sample directly in your question.

Comment: it seems like your elements wrapped in an iframe and the iframe has its own document, so you won't see the elements of the current document. Under the tab "console" you can choose an iframe and the try document.querySelectorAll and the see the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any browser settings that would affect `document.querySelectorAll()`. It's pretty core functionality.

You mentioned an `iframe`, so it's likely that is the source of the confusion. When using `iframes`, you can't access or modify the contents of the `iframe` directly from the outer level. To the outer level, it's essentially a black box. This is due to sandboxing that the browser does.

The exception to this is if the `iframe` and the main page are on the same domain (e.g., `http://example.com/page1` and `http://example.com/page2`).

If they are both on the same domain, then you can access it's window with `contentWindow`:

```
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
iframe.contentWindow // the window for the iframe
```

From there, you can access its document, and run `querySelectorAll()` against that:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll('div');
```

That will get all of the div elements in the iframe.

Comment: I've executed document.querySelector('iframe'); and I get null, but I got the point. I am going to find a way to access to the iframe content properly.